# Strange error message being returned when creating calendar event

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-calendar-api

I'm creating a google calendar event using the Node.js Google Client API, I'm requesting a conference be created with the event using the following object:

```
var conferenceData = 
{                    
    createRequest: 
    {
        requestId: uuid(),
        conferenceSolutionKey:
        {
           type: "hangoutsMeet"
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error back from the server saying: `Error: Invalid conference type value.` Which doesn't make any sense, since, according to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) `hangoutsMeet` is an acceptable value:

> The possible values are:
>
> - "**eventHangout**" for Hangouts for consumers (http://hangouts.google.com)
> - "**eventNamedHangout**" for classic Hangouts for G Suite users (http://hangouts.google.com)
> - "**hangoutsMeet**" for Hangouts Meet (http://meet.google.com)

Anybody have any idea why it could be returning that error?

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the same problem at the moment.
I believe it actually comes from the fact that the calendar where you try to insert the event does not accept the "hangoutsMeet" conference call type.

You can check that by using the API to get the calendar setup details, in conferenceProperties.allowedConferenceSolutionTypes:
 - https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get
 - https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars#resource

For my particular case, I can observe that the calendar only supports "eventNamedHangout", and "hangoutsMeet" is not listed.

That being said, I have no idea about how to actually make sure the "hangoutsMeet" type is supported by a specific calendar resource.

**Edit**

It seems that my problem was coming from the fact I was using a GCP service account - in that case what I observe is that only the eventNamedHangout type is supported.
When sending the very same payload to the API with an access_token obtained via the oauth dance, hangoutsMeet becomes available.

Comment: This _sounds_ right but in my case, I have the same problem as the OP and yet I seem to have "hangoutsMeet" just fine: " @conference_properties=
  #<Google::Apis::CalendarV3::ConferenceProperties:0x00007f8ffc98f308
   @allowed_conference_solution_types=["hangoutsMeet"]>,"
They have an issue tracker apparently here: https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/566224?p=1&q=componentid:191627%2B

Comment: Just FYI - using a service account with domain wide delegation that is _impersonating_ the real user seems to work ok!

Comment: Confirming that I had the same experience as @theozero -- I had to grant domain-wide delegation to my service account, then impersonate a user with rights to that calendar to be allowed to add a conference of type `hangoutsMeet`

Answer (score 1):

I got this working.  As per the [events docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) you referred to, if providing `conferenceSolution` then at least one `entryPoint` must also be provided.  Otherwise use `createRequest`:

"Either conferenceSolution and at least one entryPoint, or createRequest is required."

Comment: Can you provide an example of the payload you are using? Trying to test out the limits of what google will allow as far as putting custom info in there, and the docs on this are quite sparse...

Answer (score 0):

Does your uuid() return a string ?

and try smth like this instead :

```
const event = {
        "conferenceData": {
            "createRequest": {
                "requestId": "someRandomKey",
                "conferenceSolutionKey": {
                    "type": "hangoutsMeet"
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Yes, if I don't include the `hangoutsMeet` property, the conference is created successfully, but isnt the right conference type